# How to create a link to sysfs attribute

Tags: sysfs

I try to create a platform driver to integrate used device driver like eeprom/gpio/mux etc. Since those components already have driver to use, I try to create a link to those driver sysfs. But I found only examples to create link to directory, is there any way to create link to attribute or attribute group?

Some example code pieces are welcome